# Django error django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage

Tags: python, django, pip

I tried to install celery with redis, on localhost works OK, but on production server i got this error:

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/srv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 108, in get_response
   response = middleware_method(request)
 File "/srv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/middleware.py", line 11, in process_request
   request._messages = default_storage(request)
 File "/srv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/storage/__init__.py", line 12, in default_storage
   return import_string(settings.MESSAGE_STORAGE)(request)
 File "/srv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 33, in import_string
   six.reraise(ImportError, ImportError(msg), sys.exc_info()[2])
 File "/srv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 29, in import_string
   return getattr(module, class_name)
ImportError: Module "django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage" does not define a "FallbackStorage" attribute/class
```

Google didnt help.

I have no clue what is happening, I cant 'rollback' and get my production site working... Tried uninstall all new packages (celery, redis... ) but still getting this error.

Pip freeze:

```
amqp==1.4.9
anyjson==0.3.3
billiard==3.3.0.22
celery==3.1.20
dj-database-url==0.3.0
dj-static==0.0.6
Django==1.8.2
django-adminplus==0.3
django-appconf==1.0.1
django-crispy-forms==1.5.0
django-embed-video==1.0.0
django-kronos==0.9
django-paypal==0.2.7
django-suit==0.2.13
djangorestframework==3.1.3
gunicorn==19.1.1
kombu==3.0.33
MySQL-python==1.2.5
nodeenv==0.13.2
Pillow==3.1.1
psycopg2==2.5.1
python-crontab==2.0.1
python-dateutil==2.4.2
pytz==2015.4
redis==2.10.5
requests==2.7.0
six==1.9.0
static3==0.6.1
wheel==0.24.0
```

Can someone help me pls? I'm still django (python) rookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, I tried uninstall Django and then install it once again and all is working now. Mystery :)

Answer (score -1):

If you use the java script  for message display then there are possibility to raise this type of error.

Comment: no way! javascript has nothing to do with this